# Small question about calculus

Tags: analysis

I have this lemme from this paper: "Multiplicity results for quasi-linear problems A.Ayoujil, A.R. El Amrouss, 2008"

> We consider the truncated problem $$(\mathcal P_\pm)\begin{cases}-\Delta_pu=f_\pm(x,u) & \text{in }\Omega,  \\ u=0 & \text{on }\partial\Omega,\end{cases}$$ where $$f_\pm(x,t)=\begin{cases}f(x,t)&\text{if }\pm t\geqslant0,\\0&\text{otherwise}.\\\end{cases}$$ We denote by $u^+:=\max(u,0)$ and $u^-:=\max(-u,0)$ the positive and negative parts of $u$.
>
> **Lemma 2.2.** *All solutions of $(\mathcal{P}_+)$ (resp. $(\mathcal{P}_-)$) are positive (resp. negative) solutions of $(\mathcal{P})$.*
>
> **Proof.** Define $\Phi_\pm : W_0^{1,p}(\Omega) \to \mathbb{R},$
>   $$
> \Phi_\pm(u) = 
> \frac{1}{p} \int\limits_\Omega\left|\nabla u\right|^p dx -
> \int\limits_\Omega F_\pm(x, u) \, dx,
> $$
>   where $F_\pm(x,t) = \int\limits_0^t f_\pm(x,s)\,ds$. It is well known that under subcritical growth condition on $f$, $\Phi_\pm$ is well defined on $W_0^{1,p}(\Omega)$, weakly lower semi-continous and $C^1$-functionals.
>
> Let $u$ be a solution of $(\mathcal{P}_+)$, or equivalently, $u$ be a critical point of $\Phi_+$. Taking $v = u^-$ in
>   $$
> \langle\Phi_+'(u),v\rangle =
> \int\limits_\Omega\left(
> \left|\nabla u\right|^{p-2}\nabla u\nabla v - f_+(x,u)v
> \right) dx = 0,
> $$
>   shows that $||u^-||=0$, so $u^-=0$ and $u=u^+$ is also a critical point of $\Phi$ with critical value $\Phi(u) = \Phi_+(u)$. Furthermore, by Anane[1], $u\in L^\infty(\Omega)\cap C^1(\Omega)$. The maximum principle implies that either $u > 0$ or $u\equiv 0$. Similarly, nontrivial critical points of $\Phi_-$ are negative solutions of $(\mathcal{P})$. $\quad\square$

I dont understand why $||u^-||_{W^{1,p}_0}=0$ ???

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because $f_+(x,u)u_-=0$ and on the RHS of the last display formula you get $\int_\Omega|\nabla u_-|^p dx$.

Comment: Why ? what is $f(u,v)$ ??? we have $f_+(t,u) v$

Comment: Sorry for the misprint. See corrected answer. By the way, $f_+(x,u)v$, not $f_+(t,u)v$.

Comment: but why $f_+(x,u) u^-=0$ ?and why we obtain the norme of $u^-$ ?

Comment: Because $f_+(x,u)=0$ for $u<0$ and that is where $u_-\ne0$. What remains in the integrand is $-|\nabla u|^{p-2}\nabla u\nabla u_-=-|\nabla u_-|^p$, because the product is zero where $u_-$ is zero and $u=-u_-$ where $u_-$ is nonzero.

Comment: but $u$ is a solution of $(P_+)$ then why $u<0$ ?

Comment: In fact, the argument proves that $u\ge0$. Indeed, the only points where $u<0$ are those points where $u_-=\max\{-u,0\}>0$, and we have just proved that $u_-=0$ everywhere.

Comment: So how to give an answer to my question ?

Comment: You get $||u_-||_{W_0^{1,p}}=\int_\Omega|\nabla u_-|^pdx=0$.

Comment: but why i dont understand nothing tel us that $f_+(x,u)u^-$ is equal to 0 !

Comment: If $u(x)\ge0$ then $u_-(x)=0$. If $u(x)<0$, then $f_+(x,u)=0$. Hence the product $u_-(x)f_+(x,u)$ is always $0$.

Comment: if $u^-(x)=0$ then $f_+(x,u)u^-=0$ and also $|\nabla u|^{p-2}\nabla u\nabla u^-=0$ !

Comment: Yes, you are right, note also that $|\nabla u(x)|^{p-2}\nabla u\nabla u_-=0=-|\nabla u_-(x)|^p$ in this case. And if $u_-(x)\ne0$, then still $f_+(x,u(x))u_-(x)=0$ but $|\nabla u(x)|^{p-2}\nabla u\nabla u_-=-|\nabla u_-(x)|^p$. Thus, the integrand is  $-|\nabla u_-(x)|^p$ in all cases.

Comment: $-|\nabla u|^{p-2}\nabla u\nabla u_-=-|\nabla u_-|^p$ when $u=u^-$ but in other cases why ?

Comment: In other cases because both sides are zero and hence equal to each other.